# Migrating tables to a new database in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a database with two tables which are being merged into. Some fields are missing some fields mantain but they are in a new database.

One have ~263,975 rows and other ~134,533.

With that said, which could be the best method to do this?

I've thought about exporting to raw SQL and then alter the insert but seems to be a little bit rough for files of about 70 Mb that will crash almost any text editor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method is:-

1. Write a query which- fetch only required field and required data from both tables, You can use `JOIN` or `UNION` and create a new table.
2. Export this new table.
3. Import this new table in new database.

Comment: That seems fine! What about fields that aren't present but should be filled?

Comment: you can insert the data in them as well. What you need to do is first create a table with the fields you want and write a JOIN or UNION `SELECT ... INSERT` query to fill the data.

Comment: The table is created but, for example, I have a field called "type" which isn't present in any table so I have to fill it manually. How could I do that?

Comment: What will be the possible values for this field? I think it will be having not more than 4-5 possible values. right? If this is the case you can write the `IF` with mysql and fill that column. Don't need to fill manually, you can handle it with query.